# Sending data to USB printer in Delphi

Tags: delphi, usb, vcl, zebra-printers

How do I send text commands to a printer connected in the USB port using Delphi?

I have a Zebra TLP2844 printer and want to program a direct communication with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the WinAPI function [`Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing it the `Printer.Canvas.Handle` as the first parameter and `PASSTHROUGH` as the `nEscape` parameter.

```
var
  YourCommand: String;
begin
  YourComamnd := 'Your command here';

  if Escape(Printer.Canvas.Handle, 
                PASSTHROUGH, 
                Length(YourCommand), 
                PChar(YourCommand), 
                nil) <> 0 then
    // Handle return value (listed in docs link above)
  else
    // send next command
```

`Escape` is defined in the `Windows` unit. Note you have to call `Printer.StartPage` before using this function in order to prepare the printer driver to receive content.

Comment: In Delphi XE3 Printer.Canvas.Handle would be Printer.Canvas.BufferHandle?

Comment: In VCL.Printers, it's `Printer.Canvas.Handle`, which is the printer's `HDC`. I don't see `Canvas.BufferHandle` in the documentation anywhere. If you're not using the VCL, you should say so and add the appropriate FireMonkey tag to your question. :-) Just found `BufferHandle`, and no; that's a `THandle`, and `Escape` is looking for a handle to a device context (`HDC`).

Comment: Looking at the source for `FMX.Printer.Win.pas`, there's a `Canvas` defined for the `TPrinter`. I don't know if it has a Windows-compatible HDC available (I doubt it), but you might be able to use the `Printer.Handle`, which it says is an HDC. I don't know if it will work with `Escape` or not, because I haven't tried it.

Comment: I was confused by the help that pointed me to FMX when I tried to see wich unit defined the TPrinter class. I need the VCL indeed. Thank you.

Comment: I have some more problems here. Couldn't fit it in a comment nor could I see how to edit the question to add that info. So I posted a new question on the same subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969323/sending-commands-directly-to-zebra-epl

Comment: A new question was exactly the right thing to do, as it's a totally new question. :-)